# Not receiving correctly multipart form data with PHP Klein

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, multipartform-data

I have a big issue with receiving data from multipart form request sent by my reactJS front-end to the PHP api handled with Klein.
I just tried to send with Javascript this fetch request

```
 const data = new FormData();
    data.append('sourceId', sourceId);
    data.append('customerId', customerId);
    const resp = await fetch(URL_CREATE_DOC, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=stackoverflowrocks',
      }
```

and then to receive in my PHP Api with this

```
var_dump($request->files()->all());
```

but there's no data ! In the header, I see that the data is well sent by the front and when I make a var_dump($request->server()), I see the CONTENT_LENGHT changing if I send files. I think I don't do something well but how can I get the data from the multipart request ?

Comment: FormData automatically creates the random boundary value itself. By trying to specify `boundary=stackoverflowrocks` in the `Content-Type` header, you are probably ruining things here - the header says the boundary the body parser should look for was `stackoverflowrocks`, but in reality, it is likely a completely different one. Do not set the Content-Type header yourself - fetch & FormData are capable of figuring this out themselves. https://muffinman.io/blog/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cbroe ! This was my issue, I just deleted the ```Content-Type``` line and it worked ! Two days on this and you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [readme](https://github.com/klein/klein.php):

```
$request->
    id($hash = true)                    // Get a unique ID for the request
    paramsGet()                         // Return the GET parameter collection
    paramsPost()                        // Return the POST parameter collection
    paramsNamed()                       // Return the named parameter collection
    cookies()                           // Return the cookies collection
    server()                            // Return the server collection
    headers()                           // Return the headers collection
    files()                             // Return the files collection
    body()                              // Get the request body
    params()                            // Return all parameters
    params($mask = null)                // Return all parameters that match the mask array - extract() friendly
    param($key, $default = null)        // Get a request parameter (get, post, named)
```

`files()` is exclusively for uploaded files, which you don't seem to have; your values can be found in POST data, which means any one of `paramsPost()`, `params()` or `param($name)` would be correct.

Comment: Thank you @Duroth for your answer. It's my fault, I put the wrong line in my issue, indeed, the ```$request->files()->all()``` is only to get files. I used this when I tried to send files. Even when I used ```paramsPost()``` or ```params()```, it didn't work, it showed an empty array. @CBroe brought the solution for me.